# Beautiful Soup find using Persian string

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, persian

I want to find all elements containing a string using Beautiful Soup in Python.

It works when I use non-Persian characters, but not when I use Persian characters.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
QUERY = 'رشته فارسی'
URL = 'http://www.example.com'
headers = {
  'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 . . . "
}
request = urllib2.Request(URL, headers=headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
response_content = response.read().decode('utf8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response_content, 'html.parser')
fetched = soup.find_all(text=QUERY)
print(fetched)
```

For the code above, the output is `[]`, but it works if I use ASCII in the query.

Is there any UTF-8 conversion or something to solve it :) ?

Comment: You need to match the encoding on the page

Comment: @PadraicCunningham how can I do it ?

Comment: shouldn't you use utf-8 or UTF-8 instead of utf8 ?

Comment: You are using Python 3, right? I dont know persian but have you tried [normalizing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) `QUERY` and `response_content`? Just because 2 strings look the same, they dont have to consist of the same codepoints (they dont have to look the same for the computer).

Comment: When you `print(repr(QUERY))` what do you see?

Answer (score 3):

```py
    #-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import urllib2
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    QUERY = 'خدمات'
    URL = 'https://bayan.ir/service/bayan/'
    headers = {
          'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 . . . "
    }
    request = urllib2.Request(URL, headers=headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    response_content = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response_content, 'html.parser')
    fetched = soup.find_all(string=QUERY)
    print(fetched)
```

It works!

Comment: **you must send exact string**
check [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument)